# Set up install referrer and revenue tracking on iOS

Tags: ios, install-referrer, revenue

We need to track install sources and total revenue per each install source, on iOS (we want to track effectivity of crosslinking and adware campaigns).

I.e. users from "source1" make m installs and bring us n $.

It was easy to implement on Android.

How we can reach the same on iOS?

Native iTunes Connect analytics is not so good, as for me, because only 30% of our users shared analytics with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoogleAnalytics to do that.

Check this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

Comment: As far as I know, GA, works only with adware sources. I.e. if I want to track crosslink from our first app to second - it will be impossible.